# addClass/removeClass doesn't apply

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I tried to apply the addClass and removeClass for one of the rows in my table and for some reason the addClass and removeClass styles are not applied.
Since they were not working I tried to use css but this one is making my code more redundant applying the same style to some of the fields. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

From firebug

```
<tr style="color: red; font-weight: bold; background: none repeat scroll 0% 0% rgb(255, 255, 255); cursor: pointer;" class="state-selected"><td style="padding:2.5px 0px 2.5px 2px;">Equipment</td></tr>



.state-selected {
    }
```

and I have defined the style on the top of my jsp page

```
<style type="text/css">
.state-selected {
    color: 'red';
    font-weight: 'bold';
}
 </style>    
$("#index tr:gt(0)").hover(

    function () {
        $(this).css({
            'background': '#e9e7e7',
            'cursor': 'pointer'
        });
    }, function () {
        $(this).css({
            'background': '#ffffff',
            'cursor': 'pointer'
        });
    }).click(function (e) {
        $("#index tr").removeClass('state-selected');
        $(this).addClass('state-selected');

    });
```

Comment: Is that CSS in a `<style>` block?  If not, then that's your problem.  If it is, then you should have pasted it into the question more accurately to reflect that.

Comment: Without actually seeing an example that contains all the css and html it is hard to say. It is possible there is an overriding style on the TD's or as the prior comment a missing style block.

Comment: Try `tr.state-selected { ... }` and your css classes must be in external file or in html file in `<style>` block.

Comment: a missed semicolon can be culprit.

Comment: @Pointy Ofcourse I do have the style block defined. I was able to apply the styles for other elements but only the addClass and removeClass are not applying the styles

Comment: You have one closing `});` too much.

Comment: I am sorry, the extra }); was for the document.ready(function() {

Answer (score 2):

Using the `css()` call, you are creating inline styles. These always override those defined in stylesheets (except when `!important` is used, but that's best avoided).

The point is, if you use `css()` then class names won't apply if they define the same properties. First remove the CSS styles you added (`{'color':'', 'font-weight':''}`) and then the class name should fall into place.

Comment: Since the styles are not applied using the class I have been using .css().

Comment: @user525146: You should only post one example code, not mix your solutions.